# When generalizing monad, performance drops nearly 50%

Tags: performance, haskell, monad-transformers

I have code that does some parsing of files according to specified rules. The whole parsing takes place in a monad that is a stack of ReaderT/STTrans/ErrorT.

```hs
type RunningRule s a = ReaderT (STRef s LocalVarMap) (STT s (ErrorT String Identity)) a
```

Because it would be handy to run some IO in the code (e.g. to query external databases), I thought I would generalize the parsing, so that it could run both in Identity or IO base monad, depending on the functionality I would desire. This changed the signature to:

```
type RunningRule s m a = ReaderT (STRef s LocalVarMap) (STT s (ErrorT String m)) a
```

After changing the appropriate type signatures (and using some extensions to get around the types) I ran it again in the Identity monad and it was ~50% slower. Although essentially nothing changed, it is much slower. Is this normal behaviour? Is there some simple way how to make this faster? (e.g. combining the ErrorT and ReaderT (and possibly STT) stack into one monad transformer?)

To add a sample of code - it is a thing that based on a parsed input (given in C-like language) constructs a parser. The code looks like this:

```
compileRule :: forall m. (Monad m, Functor m) =>
        -> [Data -> m (Either String Data)] -- For tying the knot
        -> ParsedRule -- This is the rule we are compiling 
        -> Data -> m (Either String Data) -- The real parsing
compileRule compiled (ParsedRule name parsedlines) = 
    \input -> runRunningRule input $ do
         sequence_ compiledlines
   where
       compiledlines = map compile parsedlines
       compile (Expression expr) = compileEx expr >> return ()
       compile (Assignment var expr) = 
       ...
       compileEx (Function "check" expr) = do
           value <- expr
           case value of
               True -> return ()
               False -> fail "Check failed"
           where
                code = compileEx expr
```

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations and profile it with criterion?  What were the profiling steps you took to find this slowdown?

Comment: Compiled with optimizations, enabled profiling and and ran it with +RTS -p, compared the outputs - the result suggested mostly nothing (apart from that it likely has something to do with the monads). I used the general 'time' to check the performance, on my test data it took 2 seconds with 'hardcoded Identity' and 3 seconds when allowed to set the Identity monad as a 'parameter'.

Comment: "and using some extensions to get around the types" <- may indicate that something did change as a result. Extended code example in question could help to find explanation sooner.

Comment: I had to use Scoped Type variables, as I am internally passing some internal functions to `lift $ runST` and I needed to have 'rigid m' but 'free s'. It's really the type signature that changed.

Answer (score 12):

This is not so unusual, no. You should try using `SPECIALIZE` pragmas to specialize to `Identity`, and maybe `IO` too. Use `-ddump-simpl` and watch for warnings about rule left hand sides being too complicated. When specialization doesn't happen as it should, GHC ends up passing around typeclass dictionaries at runtime. This is inherently somewhat inefficient, but more importantly it prevents GHC from inlining class methods to enable further simplification.

Comment: I tried to add it, it seems to have worked in the sense that ddump-simpl seems to show it is indeed specialized (had to add INLINABLE too). It had negligible effect on performance. The thing is I am building lots of lambda expressions running in this monad, maybe they do not get specialized?

Comment: I think we'd need to actually compare the original code to the generalized.

Comment: @ondra, I meant to ping you on that last comment.

Comment: I tried to create my own Monad Transformer combining the layers; somehow hardwiring the Identity to original was fastest (1.9s), continuing with ST-like monad with hardwired Identity (2s), State hardwired (2.4s), State/ST-like generalized (2.7s) and the slowest is the original stack of Monads generalized (~3s). I will probably stick with the State-like monad (it's simplest). The -fdump-simpl is just HUGE (12M with the specialized version), I am not quite sure where to start. The generalized code differs from the non-generalized only by signature and some runIdentity/monadic details.

Comment: @ondra, I was only suggesting dumping simplification in this particular case to see if you would get warning messages in the dump about rule LHS too complicated when you added `SPECIALIZE` pragmas. If you actually want to read that core, you generally need to use something like `-dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures` to bring it down to a reasonable size.

Comment: I did, no warning was generated (compiled with -Wall -ddump-simpl). When I run it in IO monad (the exact same code), it gets to about 3.5s, but I would expect that this could happen.

Comment: @ondra, you've reached the limit of my ability to guess wildly without seeing actual code. Sorry.

Comment: @ondra, could you link to the real before and after versions, that we could actually compile?